# Can not return a new instance of a class in Java

Tags: java

what I want to do here is that I want to make an instance out of class TypeOperator, and make this instance has the type TypeExp, but when I create the function `newTypeOperator` down below there are always some errors.

```
class TypeOperator extends TypeExp{
    private String operator;
    private TypeList types;
    public TypeOperator(String operator, TypeList types){
        this.operator = operator;
        this.types = types;
    }

    public static TypeExp newTypeOperator(String operator, TypeList types) {
        return new TypeOperator(String operator, TypeList types);
    }
}
```

And I have this another class called TypeExp.

```
abstract class TypeExp{

}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code, thanks

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Remove parameter types from your constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
return new TypeOperator(operator, types);
```

You are passing variables into the constructor, so having types there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to specify the variable type/class when declaring something, after that you only use the identifier.